# Button inside recyclerView click unnormal

Tags: android

I set a button inside recyclerView where i click it Toast will show "RecyclerViewOnClick" not "Button inside RecyclerView".

If i want to show "Button inside RecyclerView",i have to click the button longClick.

How can i click the button inside recyclerView onClick ,and it will show "Button inside RecyclerView" not "RecyclerViewOnClick" ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I use recyclerView click Model like this:

```
public class RecyclerViewClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public RecyclerViewClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context,
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){ 

                    @Override
                    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                        View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                        if(childView != null && mListener != null){
                            mListener.onItemClick(childView,recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(childView));
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                        View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                        if(childView != null && mListener != null){
                            mListener.onItemLongClick(childView,recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(childView));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        if(mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
            return true;

        }else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
    }
}
```

My button inside recyclerView onClick function is under MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private Button creditCardPayment;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            creditCardPayment=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.creditCardPayment);
            //I want to show this toast when i onClick button.
            creditCardPayment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Button inside RecyclerView",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

It is my fragment declare recyclerView click model:

```
    @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewClickListener(getActivity(),recyclerView, new RecyclerViewClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    //When i click the button , the toast show "RecyclerViewOnClick" not "Button //inside recyclerView"                    

Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"RecyclerViewOnClick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

                        }
                    }));
                }
```

It is my recyclerView layout, i set a button:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paymentStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/paymentStatus"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
        //onClick over here
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/creditCardPayment"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/corner_light_dark_blue"
            android:text="@string/creditCardPayment"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. If you understand where the Toast is being called from, just put the code you need in there.

Comment: check this example http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/

Comment: thanks for responding , may be i put the layout code can let you understand my problem, i updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have set `TouchListener` to recylerview you never gonna have the `onClick` event of the button at the same time. Button's `OnClick` listener is fine but RecyclerView's `OnTouchListener` is taking the precedence over the `OnClick` listener of the Button.

So the best way to implement both is to set the whole item's click listener just like the Button's click listener.

Remove this

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewClickListener(getActivity(),recyclerView, new RecyclerViewClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        //When i click the button , the toast show "RecyclerViewOnClick" not "Button //inside recyclerView"                    

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"RecyclerViewOnClick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

    }
}));
```

Instead add this call on at the ViewHolder just like below.

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private Button creditCardPayment;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        creditCardPayment=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.creditCardPayment);
        //I want to show this toast when i onClick button.
        creditCardPayment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Button inside RecyclerView",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //recyclerView's item click
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"RecyclerViewOnClick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                    
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks @android_griezmann , you clarify my issue . So if i have a button in recyclerView , i have to quit this recyclerView model  :(